# HOw to add values from a column to another column

Tags: sas

I have sas code as shown below

```
data have;
infile cards dlm=',';
informat product_Id $8. type $8. Description $20.;
input Product_ID    Type      Description;
cards;
12, A, Made of wood
12, B, Made of wood
25, C, Made of steel
15, D, Made of iron
12, F, Made of paper
;

proc sort data=have;
by product_id description type;
run;

data want;
set have;
length type_cat $20.;
by product_id description type;
retain type_cat;
if first.product_id then call missing(type_cat);
type_cat = catx(", ", type_cat, type);

if last.description then do;
description = catt(description, " (", type_cat, ")");
output;
end;

run;
```

I'm expecting output to be like shown below, please help on what am i missing.Please note that the type is added to the description within paranthesis only when description is the same between the products
I'm expecting output to be like shown below

```
Product_ID description
12         Made of paper(F)
12         Made of Wood(A,B)
25         Made of steel (C)
15         Made of iron ( D)
```

Comment: Why are you clearing the list when you start a new PRODUCT when you want the list to only include the types within one combination of PRODUCT and DESCRIPTION?   Also I thought from your previous question that PRODUCT and DESCRIPTION went together.  Why does product 12 now have two different descriptions? Is this a different dataset?

Answer (score 0):

Us the `BY` statement option `NOTSORTED`.  You will be able to `first.` and `last.` processing within the **contiguous** group. You will not need to sort the data -- indeed you expected output indicates no additional sorting.

I also changed the types reset to occur at first.descriptopm

```
data want;
  set have;
  by product_id description NOTSORTED;   /* <-------- */

  length types $20.;
  retain types;

  if first.description then call missing(types);
  types = catx(", ", types, type);

  if last.description then do;
    description = catt(description, " (", types, ")");
    output;
  end;
  keep product_id description;
run;
```

[image]

Nina says the code *doesn't work* for the below data, where rows that have 12 & "Made Of Wood" are not contiguous.

```
data have; 
  infile cards dlm=','; 
  informat product_Id $8. type $8. Description $20.; 
  input Product_ID Type Description; 
cards;
12, A, Made of wood 
12, B, Made of wood 
25, C, Made of steel 
15, D, Made of iron 
12, F, Made of wood 
28, G, Made of paper 
;
```

Seems to work fine

[image]

If you want all items of a group to be together Wood(A,B,F), do a `Proc SORT` before the DATA step.

Comment: the code does not work when data is like below , will you please review and advise what i should change on the code?
data have;
infile cards dlm=',';
informat product_Id $8. type $8. Description $20.;
input Product_ID    Type      Description;
cards;
12, A, Made of wood
12, B, Made of wood
25, C, Made of steel
15, D, Made of iron
12, F, Made of wood
28, G, Made of paper
;